# React Accordion transition got difficulties

Tags: css, reactjs

[Got difficulties to transitions between states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaqVJ.png)

```
 <div className="accordion-item">
    <h2 className="accordion-header">
       <button className={`accordion-button ${!showAccordion ? "collapsed" : ""}`} onClick={() => setShowAccordion(!showAccordion)}>
          Sample Text
       </button>
    </h2>
    <div className={`accordion-collapse collapse ${showAccordion ? "show" : ""}`}>
       <div className="accordion-body">
          <p>
               Example Text
          </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```
.accordion-button{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 20px 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333333;
    color: var(--bs-gray-900);
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.15s ease;
}
.accordion-button::after{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    content: "";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.25rem;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M3.125 10H16.875' stroke='%2377878F' stroke-width='1.5' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3Cpath d='M10 3.125V16.875' stroke='%2377878F' strokeWidth='1.5' strokeLinecap='round' strokeLinejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed){
    border: 1px solid var(--bs-primary-500);
    box-shadow: none;
    background: var(--bs-primary-500);
    color: white;
}
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M3.125 10H16.875' stroke='white' stroke-width='1.5' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.collapse:not(.show){
  display: none;
}
```

In this project, I got difficulties when trying to transform the accordion from collapse state to show as I would like to add transition effects of opening up and down the collapsed area and also want to have the button besides rotate when changing the state. Are there any possible solutions to have transitions between collapsed and showing state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a **Callapse.tsx** component like this :

```html
        //src/helpers/index.js
        import { clsx } from 'clsx';
        export function mergeClasses(...args) {
          return clsx(args);
        }


        //src/components/Collapse.jsx
        import { mergeClasses } from '../helpers';
        import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'; 

       
        export function Collapse({ open, children, innerClassName }) {
          const refParent = useRef(null);
          const refChild = useRef(null);

          useEffect(() => {
            if (refParent.current && refChild.current) {
              if (open) {
                console.log('is opened');

                refParent.current.setAttribute(
                  'style',
                  `max-height:${refChild.current.offsetHeight}px`
                );
              } else {
                refParent.current.setAttribute('style', 'max-height:0px');
              }
            }
          }, [open]);

          return (
            <div
              ref={refParent}
              className={mergeClasses(
                'collapse-parent',
                { 'max-h-0': !open }
              )}
            >
              <div className={innerClassName || ''} ref={refChild}>
                {children}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }

        //src/app.jsx
        import './styles.css'
        
        export default function App(){
          const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
          
          const handleToggleOpen = () => setOpen(!open);

          return(
            <>
              <button onClick={handleToggleOpen} className="accordion-header">
                Sample Text
              </button>
              <Collapse open={open}>
                  <div className="accordion-body">
                    Example Text
                  </div>
              </Collapse>
            </>
          )
        }
        
        //src/styles.css
        .collapse-parent{
          width: 100%;
          transition: all 300ms linear;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        .max-h-0{
          max-height: 0;
        }
```

in this **Collapse** component height of it set bas on children height then wa can set **transition** on max-height .

Comment: Are there any solutions using jsx format as the above solution is complicated that I could not apply to my case?

Comment: Any possible solutions in jsx to have accordion collapsed and expanded with animations?

Comment: Yes, I updated the above answer for you